# How to add JSON files webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webpack, gulp

Sorry, I am not sure how to formulate my question.
I am trying to make a project with the following file structure

```
webpack.config.js
|— src
|— |— index.ejs
|— |— assets
|— |—|—js
|— |—|—|—global.js
|— |—|—|—i18n
|— |—|—|—|—en.json
|— |—|—|—|—fr.json
(bunch of other files)
```

This is what my webpack looks like:

```
import { scripts as config } from './tasks/config';
const isDevelop = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    'assets/js/common': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/common.js`,
    'assets/js/top': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/top.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.messagestore': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.messagestore.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.fallbacks': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.fallbacks.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.language': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.language.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.parser': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.parser.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.emitter': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.emitter.js`,
    'assets/js/jquery.i18n.emitter.bidi': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/jquery.i18n.emitter.bidi.js`,
    'assets/js/global': `${config.srcRoot}/assets/js/global.js`,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' }],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
  },
  devtool: isDevelop ? 'source-map' : false,
};
```

On loading index.ejs, global.js is called and contains the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.i18n().load( {
    'en': './js/i18n/en.json',
    'fr': './js/i18n/fr.json'
  } ).done( function() { console.log('done!') } );
});
```

My problem is that the browser cannot find the json files and gives me the following error:

```
:3000/js/i18n/en.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:3000/js/i18n/fr.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

webpack outputs the files to a temporary directory and then serves the temporary directory.

so you need to use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy the resource to the output directory, in order for it to be accessable

Comment: Ah, that might make sense.
How do you achieve that?
Like this?
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'assets/js/i18n/', to: '/js/i18n/' },
      ],
    }),
  ],